# Removing unwanted spaces from WMIC output

Tags: batch-file

In my user management batch file for any computer it generates a list of users that a user has input as authorized and compares it to a list of all users

To accomplish this I append users to the end of a file and then use

```
"Wmic useraccount where "localaccount=true" get name > AllUsers.txt"
```

only problem with this is a get an output similar to

```
    "user1            "
    "user2            "
    "UnAuthorizedUser "
```

without the quotes but the space is still there, This is a problem because I use findstr to compare the all users to auth users

```
    findstr /vig:AuthUsers.txt AllUsers.txt > UnauthorizedUsers.txt
```

this should output something similar to

```
    "UnAuthorizedUser"
```

given that user1 and user2 are authorized.
the problem is that it outputs blank text because the authorized users do not have the spaces that the "AllUsers.txt" contains so its seeing what should be "user1" as "user1______" (pretend that the underscores are space), therefore it outputs a blank.

My question with all of this is simply, is there a command that can get rid of a space at the end of a word on multiple lines of a text file? or better yet make findstr ignore the spaces all together?

Comment: Actually I believe your problem is that the WMIC output is in unicode.

Comment: Recommend transitioning to PowerShell.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have yet to try powershell due to a lack of sources for me to learn from

Comment: There are plenty of free PowerShell learning resources on the Internet.

Comment: Is there one that you would recommend?

Comment: Easy to learn powershell with just some simple Google searches.  I started using it back in 2008 just by searching for commands that would do the same things as my batch files. Wasn't too hard to figure out.  I still mainly program in batch files and vbscript because that is what is usually quick and dirty for the stuff we do at work but I use SS64 to reference most of Microsoft's scripting languages. Here is there [powershell reference](https://ss64.com/ps/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that WMIC output is unicode and your match file is ascii.  So you need some way to make the WMIC output be normal ascii. You can do this by using another FOR command which will help translate the characters into single byte.

```
@echo off

(FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G IN ('wmic UserAccount where "LocalAccount=True" get Name') DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%H in ("%%G") do @echo %%H |findstr /VIG:AuthUsers.txt
))>UnauthorizedUsers.txt
```

Comment: Seemed to work just fine! I will test it further when I get to my house and find out if I can incorporate it with my "Automatic" Unauthorized User Script